# Checking two tables where 1 result can be NULL in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I'm trying to look up two tables where tableA has an ID from tableB and have it return the name of tableB, but if the ID is NULL just return NULL. As of now I have:

```
SELECT vehicle.Id, vehicle.Registration, (case when vehicle.ChecklistId != NULL then
checklist.Name else NULL end) FROM vehicle, checklist WHERE vehicle.ChecklistId =
checklist.Id OR vehicle.ChecklistId IS NULL"
```

However this just return nothing as there's currently nothing in the checklist table. Am I missing something or just doing it wrong completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either simply select the value:

```
select 
  vehicle.id, 
  vehicle.registration, 
  (select checklist.name from checklist where checklist.id = vehicle.checklistid )
from vehicle;
```

Or use an outer join:

select

```
  vehicle.id, 
  vehicle.registration, 
  checklist.name
from vehicle
left join checklist on checklist.id = vehicle.checklistid;
```

EDIT: As to your statement: You should not use that old join syntax where you just list the tables comma-separated. It is prone to errors. What you are doing is this:

- join each vehicle where vehicle.ChecklistId IS NOT NULL with the matching checklist, if any
- join each vehicle where vehicle.ChecklistId IS NULL with *all* checklists

In your case checklist is empty so both result sets are empty. If there were matches in checklist, however, you would get too many records, because you would cross join all your vehicles where ChecklistId IS NULL with the checklist table.

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. It's odd that my lecturer never mentioned join when telling us about mySQL, it seems quite important. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT vehicle.Id, vehicle.Registration, (case when vehicle.ChecklistId != NULL then
checklist.Name else NULL end) FROM vehicle LEFT OUTER JOIN checklist 
ON vehicle.ChecklistId =checklist.Id OR vehicle.ChecklistId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this :

```
SELECT vehicle.Id, vehicle.Registration, checklist.Name FROM vehicle LEFT JOIN checklist ON vehicle.ChecklistId =checklist.Id OR vehicle.ChecklistId IS NULL
```